# how to check if one property of entity model return nil in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new in swift.

I have a object of entity example: var person=Person()

person have name, but docent have a lastName.
how to check if person.lastName is nil,
I have tried but dosen't work .
please help

Comment: Can you show the code for your person class?  Is your `lastName` property declared as an optional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var lastName:String?;

if (person.lastName == nil)
{
  //Do something.
}
else
{
   //Do something
}
```